# make a div 100% to body if its in a container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for my responsive layout. Within the `.container` I want to have a div which isn't limited to the `width` of the container. Furthermore I want it to be stretched over the full body. I could place the div outside the `.container` but I don't want to mess around with absolute positioning or similar.

How can I make a div `100%` to the body, even if the parent div is not filling the whole width of the body.

```
.div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 6px;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: But this is what absolute positioning is for

Comment: this is not achievable without positioning

Comment: but how would I make sure that the div is always at the correct position related to the height of other divs inside the container.

Comment: This is totally not the same question. The duplicate reference is about 100% body height. This is about width, and specifically displaying beyond .container width.

Answer (score 0):

Use class .container-fluid instead of .container. Bootstrap provide .container-fluid class to make full screen div.

If you are specific to some requirement please share code as well to understand better.